# Reducing canvas size of SVG image to the actual painted size in Qt Quick

Tags: qt, canvas, svg, qtquick2

**Hello everyone! :)**

I am developing a Qt Quick Controls 2 application, and I need to scale down an SVG image that is a part of a ColumnLayout to fit the screen height. Here is my code:

```
Page {
    title: "About"

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 20

        Image {
            id: app_logo
            source: "images/app_logo.svg"
            mipmap: true
            Layout.maximumWidth: Math.min(parent.width, 300)
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop
            verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignTop
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        }

        Label {
            text: "Version 0.1"
            font.pointSize: 15
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
        }
    }
}
```

The original SVG size is *1200x500*, and the resulting painted image is *300x125*, which is also displayed by paintedWidth and paintedHeight properties. The problem I face is that SVG's canvas is not changed, remaining *1200x500*, which moves other controls (e.g. the label) out of the screen:

[image: Application screenshot]

How do I set the canvas size to the actual painted size not causing a binding loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using SVG images in Qt Quick, change their sourceSize to match their item size:

```
Image {
        id: app_logo
        source: "images/app_logo.svg"
        mipmap: true
        Layout.maximumWidth: Math.min(parent.width, 300)
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop
        verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignTop
        sourceSize: Qt.size(width, height) //important
    }
```

The highlighted line changes canvas (rendering) size.

Answer (score 0):

According to [`paintedHeight` documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html#paintedHeight-prop):

> When using an *Image.PreserveAspectFit* or an *Image.PreserveAspectCrop* paintedWidth or paintedHeight can be smaller or larger than width and height of the Image item.

The paintedHeight is 125 because `fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit` is set. However the `height` of image is not set and it remains to 500 pixels by default. To assign correct height without causing a binding loop, you can set `Layout.preferredHeight` property and calculate *PreserveAspectFit* by yourself:

```
Image {
    id: app_logo
    source: "images/app_logo.svg"
    mipmap: true
    Layout.maximumWidth: Math.min(parent.width, 300)
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop
    verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignTop

    //PreserveAspectFit 
    Layout.preferredHeight: (width / sourceSize.width) * sourceSize.height
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this code works; however, there's still a warning: `qrc:/main.qml:20:5: QML Page: Binding loop detected for property "contentHeight"`